# Hide an pre-rendered li label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've rendered an Django form field with CheckboxSelectMultiple widget in my page, now, on page load, I want to hide all unchecked checkbox option. I manage to hide the checkbox but I don't know how to hide the label associated with the checkbox. my question is, how can I hide this label as well? below is my code :
model.py

```
class model_A(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

form.py :

```
class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'edit_form'
    class Meta:
        model = model_A
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'user':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

html :

```
<div class="field">
    {{form.user}}
</div>
```

javascript :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').hide();
```

On view page source in browser :

```
<ul id="id_settings-user">
    <li><label for="id_settings-user_1"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="1" id="id_settings-user_1" style="display: none;">
 Person A</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="id_settings-user_2"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="2" id="id_settings-user_2" style="display: none;">
 Person B</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="id_settings-user_3"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="3" id="id_settings-user_3" style="display: none;">
 Person C</label>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)/[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target label then hide.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').parent().hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').closest('label').hide();
```

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="id_settings-user">
  <li><label for="id_settings-user_1"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="1" id="id_settings-user_1" checked >
 Person A</label>
  </li>
  <li><label for="id_settings-user_2"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="2" id="id_settings-user_2" >
 Person B</label>
  </li>
  <li><label for="id_settings-user_3"><input type="checkbox" name="settings-user" value="3" id="id_settings-user_3">
 Person C</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes